# Evaluating expressions and parentheses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I'm having trouble understanding how JS is processing my expressions..

This evaluates incorrectly and drops the denominator:

```
var a = document.getElementById("Acceleration").value;
var u = document.getElementById("Initial_Velocity").value;
var v = document.getElementById("Final_Velocity").value;


document.getElementById("Distance").value = (v*v-u*u)/2*a;
```

This evaluates properly:

```
document.getElementById("Distance").value = (v*v-u*u)/(2*a);
```

I'm using Dreamweaver. Thanks.

Comment: Multiplication and division operators are evaluated from left to right, so the behaviour is correct.

Comment: You can find out the order in which operators are parsed from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 0):

Well the formulas are different. You left out the parentheses `(2*a)` in the first code sample.

Comment: Ugh I'm tired and completely forgot math. sorry close please